# Mutt stopped sending email

Tags: email, mutt

I'm using `mutt` to send mail like this:

```
mutt -s "Subject" email@gmail.com <<< "Text"
```

A few days ago, `mutt` stopped working and now I am getting this error:

```
msmtp: cannot read from TLS connection: the operation timed out
msmtp: could not send mail (account default from ~/.msmtprc)
Error sending message, child exited 74 (I/O error.)
```

- version: Mutt 1.9.4
- /.muttrc:

> ```
> set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"
> set use_from=yes
> set from=my.email@gmail.com
> ```

- /.msmtprc:

> ```
> defaults
> logfile ~/msmtp.log
> account gmail
> auth on
> host smtp.gmail.com
> from my.email@gmail.com
> auth on
> tls on
> tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
> user my.email@gmail.com
> password "mypassword"
> port 587
> account default : gmail
> ```

What I've done:

I created an application specific password for Mutt on Google with 2FA but am still getting the same error.

The output of `telnet` and `ping` command shows a successful connection to the SMTP server of Gmail (smtp.gmail.com) on port 587.

Switch to port 465 and getting: `msmtp: the server sent an empty reply` with `code 76 (Remote protocol error.)`

Both port 587 and 465 works fine with `swaks -tls`, email successful delivered.

Comment: "timed out" suggests you cannot connect to port 587 on smtp.gmail.com. Did you check (even with telnet) that you are actually able to connect from your machine? Can some firewall be in place?

Comment: I'm not sure why it worked before. Google only allows OAuth2 authentication and rejects password based auth for email clients

Comment: @MatiasNGoldberg It can work with an application password, if you have one defined for your Google account (must have 2FA enabled on Google account, don't understand why, as these two have nothing to do with each other)

Comment: I ses, if you use app password then it may work, or it may break from Google's side. Because the SSL is timing out, it's possible the error is different but reported incorrectly. The root auth could be out of date, the clock could be wrong, your certs could be expired, or a newer algorithm is used which your SSL client doesn't support

Comment: @s3idani It would be very useful to run the following and post the terminal output in your question: `echo "Hello there" | msmtp --debug my_email@gmail.com` . Making the obvious substitution of your own 'testing' email address... Here is an example of a correctly working output on my own system: https://pastebin.com/4Jg9Nt8u

Comment: @andrew.46 A successful connection to the SMTP server already mentioned. BTW, i can send mail via `swaks` through both port 587 and 465 without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently too (my existing config just stopped working one day in March 2023).
I found this [page](https://seniormars.github.io/posts/neomutt/#google-gmail-and-app-specific-passwords) to get me going, in particular:

```
set from = "your_email_address"
set realname = "Your Name"

# Gmail
set imap_user = "your_email_address"
set smtp_url = "smtps://YOUR_EMAIL@smtp.gmail.com:465/"
set smtp_authenticators = 'gssapi:login'
set imap_pass = "your_app_specific_password"
set smtp_pass = "your_app_specific_password"

# Ensure TLS is enforced
set ssl_starttls = yes
set ssl_force_tls = yes
```

It seems to me that it was the TLS stanza that fixed my issue. HTH you!

Comment: I have mutt working with gmail, and I don't have those TLS entries. However, it's possible that Google has not yet rolled the changes out to my account. Thanks for your post, +1

Comment: @OrganicMarble Probably, I saw mutt users complaining about this whilst my old config was working almost a year ago if memory serves. Then it bit me. :-) Google, like most big entities, do rollouts gradually methinks.

Answer (score 0):

- You might not be able  to connect to port 587 on that host ( rate limits ? ) , ask your ISP if this problem persists
- If port 465 is open from your side [you may use the **proper ssl settings**](https://marlam.de/msmtp/msmtp.html)

  ```
  # Use TLS on port 465
  port 465
  tls on
  tls_starttls off
  ```

Comment: I can send mail via `swaks` through both port 587 and 465 without any issue. my ssl settings are the same in `mutt`

Comment: No solution as yet? I've been bitten by this issue too.